# Translate JSON MQL queries into SPARQL

Tags: json, sparql, freebase, mql

I have a punch of JSON MQL queries to query Freebase.
Is there a tool to translate them into SPARQL to use them with OpenRDF Sesame?
Thanks!

Comment: In generality, this would be a bit tricky, since a) MQL returns a tree and SPARQL returns a table, and b) in MQL a single structure controls both matching and output, while in SPARQL the two are different (SELECT vs WHERE). That said, any specific set of queries might well lend themselves to very easy conversion. Are yours all of a particular form, or are they all different? If the former, can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 1):

There are no SPARQL endpoints that I'm aware of that use the Freebase schema, so you'll not only need to translate the query language, but also map the properties between Freebase schema and whatever ontologies you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://code.google.com/p/simplesparql/